# Unable to cast "Set" in cassandra to "SortedSet" or "HashSet" in c# using DataStax C# Drive

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

the `Cassandra` table columns are like below:

```
CREATE TABLE mine.testtable (
    id int,
    listtext text,
    myid int,
    name text,
    name1 int,
    setint set<int>,
    stringtext text,
    testlist list<int>,
    testmap map<int, text>,
    testset set<text>,
    textlist list<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0
   AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
   AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
   AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
   AND comment = ''
   AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' }
   AND compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
   AND default_time_to_live = 0
   AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
   AND min_index_interval = 128
   AND max_index_interval = 2048;
```

In C#, `getColumnValue` function returns a column of a `Cassandra` row. The column could have any `Type`. My function is like this:

```
public Object getColumnValue(string tableName, string columnName, int id)
{
    string tmp = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE id={2};", columnName ,tableName, id.ToString());
    Row row = Session.Execute(tmp).GetRows().First();
    return row.GetValue(row.GetType(), columnName);
}
```

Function could be called for different column names like this:

```
 SortedDictionary<int, string> dictionary =(SortedDictionary<int, string>)getColumnValue("testtable", "testmap", 3);
 List<string> text =(List<string>)getColumnValue("testtable", "textlist", 2);
 SortedSet<int> setext = (SortedSet<int>)getColumnValue("testtable", "setint", 2);
```

when I tried to cast `setint` with type of `set<int>` to `SortedSet<int>` or `HashSet<int>` I get the error like below:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Service.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32] to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[System.Int32].

By considering that my `setint` is `set<int>` and not `list<int>`, Why do I get this execption ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the generic `Row.GetValue<T>(columnName)` method:

```
SortedSet<int> setValue = row.GetValue<SortedSet<int>>("setint");
List<int> listValue = row.GetValue<List<int>>("listint");
```